autodesk forge viewer - Autodesk.BimWalk get rid of the Navigate in First Person guide dialog when activating the extension
const bimwalkExt =
  Viewer.forgeViewer.getExtension(
    "Autodesk.BimWalk"
  );
if (!bimwalkExt.isActive()) {
  bimwalkExt.activate();
}

each time I activate the extension, the following dialog shows up

How can I prevent this dialog from showing up even when it's the first time we enter to the bim walk mode?


This should work:
viewer.prefs.set('bimWalkToolPopup', false);


thanks for the suggestion, I will verify this in a bit. Getting back to you once I try it
